# How can I disable UI animations (Motion Design) in Windows 11?

Tags: windows-11

Windows 11 comes with a new design paradigm called "Motion Design" that basically animates *everything* in the UI. You can see an example of it in [this Microsoft video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iBh2jSdVK-8).

However, as a power user, I prefer responsiveness/efficiency, so I would like to use fewer resources and have my UI feel faster by disabling this setting.

How can I turn off Motion Design?

Comment: Looks like they're playing catch-up with Apple again ;))) At least it doesn't look as horribly flat as Win10, you can see where windows actually end, at least.

Comment: @Tetsujin Most of the design changes in Windows 11 seem to be "let's emulate Apple", unfortunately... and Windows isn't the only place I've seen that recently.

Comment: Microsoft have been doing that since Win 95. Around that time I used to wear a badge saying , "Win 95 == Mac OS 89." They even said there 'would be no Win 11' …until Apple changed their 15-year stretch of calling it macOS 10. *something* last year & went "one louder" …[Compulsory Spinal Tap video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F7IZZXQ89Oc)

Answer (score 2):

You can turn this feature off by following these steps:

1. Go to Settings, and click the Accessibility menu option on the left-hand side:

   [image: Accessibility menu option in the Settings application]
2. Click on the **Visual effects** option to expand that section of options.

   [image: Visual effects option in the Accessibility menu page]
3. Toggle the **Animation effects** option slider to "Off"

   [image: The Animation effects toggle-able option]